# How do i set link in QrCode library php

Tags: php, qr-code

Very simple and may ask Before , I don't know... In my website i Integrated Qrcode library (PHP) i want to set link of Qr Image to my Website Here is my Code.

```
    QRcode::png('Hello World', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);  

    echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You need to use a valid URL, not just a folder name.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the generated HTML code from your PHP script.

Comment: Please Check my Answer is it Valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It , just Pass link in first parameter of png() function.

```
 QRcode::png('http://www.example.com', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);  

echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
```

Thanks For Whole stackover flow Community